# Managing time effects with plm package

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I have a data frame similar to this

```
Q1 <- data.frame(id=c("A","B","C","D","E"), assets = c(22,560,7,7841,785), qtr = c(1,1,1,1,1))
Q2 <- data.frame(id=c("A","B","C","D","E"), assets = c(48,767,88,7410,698), qtr = c(2,2,2,2,2))
Q3 <- data.frame(id=c("A","B","C","D","E"), assets = c(130,530,57,5000,741), qtr = c(3,3,3,3,3))
Q4 <- data.frame(id=c("A","B","C","D","E"), assets = c(77,821,101,5500,789), qtr = c(4,4,4,4,4))
df <- rbind(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)     
df$event <- ifelse(df$qtr >= 3,1,0)
df$affected <- ifelse(df$id %in% c("A","C"),1,0)
```

And I then run a regression like this

```
plm(assets ~ event + event*affected, data = df, index = c("id","qtr"), model = "within", effect = "twoways")
```

Now I would like to control for both individual and time effects, but controlling for time effects gets rid off the event coefficient. Is it possible to change when the time effects are calculated? By that I mean controlling for yearly time effects would work for me and the event coefficient should remain in that case. So is there a way of changing the time frame for the time effects calculation without changing the index, as I will still have quarterly data.

Comment: You have collinearity between `event` and `qtr`, that's why you do not have an estimated coefficient for `event`. You could run the LS dummy  variable model with `lm`: `lm(assets ~ event + event*affected + factor(qtr) + factor(id), data = df)`. This drops one of the quarters rather than `event`.

Comment: Cool, that seems like a good way to do it, thanks! Now is there a way I can remove all the factor coefficients from the summary?

Comment: one way with `dplyr` and `broom`: `tidy(fit) %>% filter(!str_detect(term, "factor"))`

Comment: Well it got rid of the factors so thanks for that. I've never worked with tibble before and it looks quite different to the plm summaries I am used to. It seems to be missing stuff like number of observations, R², the p.value is in scientific notation. Maybe just takes some getting used to or can I somehow get it back into lm output? That is also easy to extract into LateX.

Comment: try `texreg`: `texreg::screenreg(fit, custom.coef.map = list('event' = NA, 'affected' = NA, 'event:affected' = NA))`. `texreg::texreg` outputs to latex.

Comment: I actually just found a way that works for me. I just add  + factor(qtr) to the plm regression from above. Since that deals with the fixed effects with within transformation, there are only the two time dummy coefficients extra in the summary. The stargazer is what I have been using to get latex code and it has an omit command to omit unwanted explanatory variables. I think that will work nicely. Thanks for your help!